# How can i import OpenGL in anaconda python?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, vispy

I use ipython notebook on anaconda python but i have no idea how to install or import opengl.
Can anyone help me solve this ?
I use anaconda on linux xubuntu. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Which OS u are using ?

Comment: You probably need to set up a virtualenv for your IPython Notebook where you install all packages: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by David, Vispy provides OpenGL bindings for OpenGL ES 2.0. More interesting about vispy is `vispy.gloo` which provides a much easier (object oriented) way to use OpenGL.

If you need full desktop OpenGL functionality (not limited to ES 2.0), you need PyOpenGL. I think that currently it is supported (at least on Linux). This works for me:

```
conda install pyopengl
```

Alternatively, pip should work as well:

```
pip install pyopengl
```

Answer (score 5):

From anaconda, you can pip install [Vispy](http://vispy.org/), which is a numpy OpenGL data visualization framework that happens to provide a set of OpenGL ES 2.0 bindings via [vispy.gloo.gl](http://api.vispy.org/en/latest/gl.html).

```
pip install vispy

from vispy.gloo.gl import *
```

Vispy uses anaconda's PyQt4 for the QtOpenGL context.  The github repo has plenty of nice examples that show its potential beyond providing OpenGL bindings.

Pyglet also offers a fairly complete set of OpenGL Python bindings.

```
pip install pyglet

>> from pyglet.gl import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using anaconda on Windows...
Following the discussions on [G Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/y3kw9gMhVoE) there is currently (Sept.2013) no time frame set for the inclusion of PyOpenGL in the anaconda package. However, it should be possible to use the binaries from [Chris Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: Sorry not to tell earlier,but i use anaconda on xubuntu. Anyway, thanks for your reply