# Include OpenGL into Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, opengl, build, anaconda

One of the package in my `Anaconda` environment requires `OpenGL`, and since we are aiming to generate a general cross-platform recipe, using explicit dependency on `OpenGL` is not favourable. Is there a way to include `OpenGL` as a recipe, or otherwise, to be installed in an `Anaconda` environment?

Edit: install `pyopengl` will not solve as the package requires the library `libGL.so` but it cannot find...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i import OpenGL in anaconda python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114792/how-can-i-import-opengl-in-anaconda-python)

Comment: Does listing `pyopengl` as a dependency not work for you?

Comment: I get an error saying that it cannot find `libGL.so` after listing `pyopengl`...

Comment: What OS are you testing this on? There is the `vispy` package which depends on certain implementations of OpenGL and I know I've used it via Anaconda on Linux, Mac, and Windows. Your system at least has to support OpenGL.

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but `libGL.so` usually comes from from the video driver on the system. If you don't have any video driver installed or if the system didn't come with one then you need to install one.

Comment: It looks like compiling the `Mesa` package would help. Can anyone confirm this?